# Определить радиус наименьшего круга, внутрь которого попадают все точки

Tags: python, python-3.x

> Даны натуральное n и вещественные числа x1, y1, x2, y2,…, xn, yn. Рассматривая пары xi, yi как координаты точек на плоскости, определить радиус наименьшего круга (с центром в начале координат), внутрь которого попадают все эти точки.

Не понял саму задачу. Можете скинуть решения?

Comment: Можем, но не будем. Сорян ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: `Не понял саму задачу. Можете скинуть решения?` - вы уверены, что поймёте решение, не поняв условие задачи?

Comment: Постараюсь понять по решению задачи

Comment: попробуйте нарисовать на листке бумаге несколько точек на координатной сетке и еще раз перечитать вопрос...

Answer (score 3):

По сути, вопрос сводится к тому, какое расстояние между началом координат и самой удалённой от него точкой.

Алгоритм решения тривиален: вы перебираете все точки, для каждой находите расстояние до неё от центра координат, и берёте максимальное расстояние.